# PeopleSoft Rowset copy current row only

Tags: xml, peoplesoft, publisher, rowset

I have a record with several child records on a page.  I have a button on the page that triggers a report through XML Publisher via rowset.  The problem I am having is the rowset I am passing to the report contains everything in the buffer -- I want only the current context to show on the report.  What I have right now:

```
&rs_resp = CreateRowset(Record.AVZ_JD_RESP_TBL);
&rs_expr = CreateRowset(Record.AVZ_JD_EXPR_TBL);
&rs_skls = CreateRowset(Record.AVZ_JD_SKLS_TBL);
&rs_dtl = CreateRowset(Record.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL, &rs_resp, &rs_expr, &rs_skls
```

&RS0 = GetLevel0().GetRow(1).GetRowset(Scroll.AVZ_JD_DTL_TBL);
   &RS0.CopyTo(&rs_dtl);

Then I kick off the report:

```
&oReportDefn.SetRuntimeDataRowset(&rs_dtl);   
&oReportDefn.ProcessReport(&MyTemplate, &LanguageCd, &AsOfDate, &OutFormat);
```

I was previously using a Rowset.Fill on each of the rowsets (parent and child), but I the copyto method somehow seemed "cleaner" (certainly less code :-) ).  Is there a way to copy the current context only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all the rows would have got copied when you perform the rowset copy -
 
    `&RS0.CopyTo(&rs_dtl);`

You can control creating new pages for each row on the report, by using page-break in the for-each loop (that you would be using to traverse through the rowset in the template):
   `<?split-by-page-break:?>`

In case you want to print only the latest effdt rows, copy only the latest effdt rows to the &rs_dtl rowset. 
You could do this by first sorting the &RS0 rowset based on the keys using 
    `&RS0.sort(keyfield1,keyfield2,"A");`

and then loop through the sorted rowset checking for max effdt for a given set of keys.

Use the insert row function to insert the row into &rs_dtl.
    `&rs_dtl.Insertrow(&rownumber);`

Do tell me if this works.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was as I page through each effdt, I want to print the report for that effdt only - so I only want to copy that particular row

Comment: Ok. For such a case what I would suggest is copy only the latest effdt row to the &rs_dtl rowset.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question, you could do something like this:

```
Getrow().Copyto(&rs_dtl(1));
```

Comment: Extremely close -- I'm almost there - Thanks APace!  The report is now only showing the one row of data.  I may have worded my question incorrectly, but what I need to be able to do is generate the report from each row -- as I page through each row, only the row with the latest effdt seems to be getting sent to the report.